# Using Kerberos request type instead of NTLM in power-bi report server

Tags: powerbi, kerberos, reportserver

I'm having a server with `power-bi` reporting service installed and configured on it, and from my front-end that hosts the application, i've got `angular 7` with proper power-bi components installed.

Since the report is on the server and it needs authentication to login, i get a user and password fill-in prompt in my website whenever i try to access this report, and after logging in, i can see the data of my report.

I'm wondering how to use `Kerberos` authentication so that i can set-up that username and password to login automatically without asking the user to enter them every time.

What i've done so far : 
I've made and set a few `SPN` in my `active directory`, made a user in `Active Directory Users and Computer` and in it's Delegation tab, i've set it to `Use any authentication protocol` and added `MSOLAPDisco` and `MSOLAPSvc.3` to it. i've added the user account credentials that i've made to `service account` and `execution account` in power bi `Report server` then i modified the `rsreportserver` config file to use the `RSNegotiate` before NTLM.

After trying to solve the issue with the mentioned above methods, i still get a NTLM method in network monitor which is installed in the Active Directory.

Any suggestions how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.